# How to use an array-literal with _Static_assert in C?

Tags: c, static-assert, compound-literals

I want to use an array-literal of literals in a _Static_assert, but I get a compiler error saying this is not a constant expression

```
_Static_assert((int[]){2, 1, 0}[2], "err");
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Array subscripting involves pointer arithmetic and dereferencing and cannot be used as such.  What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: The value is array object is not a compilation time constant. So it cannot be used in `_Static_assert`. The C23 will introduce `constexpr` and allow it for storage specifier of compound literal what *may* make your code work.

Comment: @tstanisl when that becomes available, how would I write it? like this: ```_Static_assert((constexpr int[]){2, 1, 0}[2], "err");``` ?

Comment: Maybe, currently clang seams to support it but it does not work yet :/